# How to display php errors in a more readable format

Tags: php, error-handling

I've recently switched from WAMP/XAMPP to LAMP and one thing I found useful was the clean, formatted error reporting.  On my current server it just displays errors as plain text, and it can be hard to read through using a web browser (and not viewing source).  So is there any way to display errors similarly to WAMP, like in an HTML table with styling?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's a PHP setting, not specific to any *AMP platform, set in php.ini:

```
html_errors = 1
```

relevant docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.html-errors

Comment: u can also install xdebug to have coloring and more control over the format of your debug output. http://xdebug.org/

Comment: This question/answer is heavily underrated.

Answer (score 5):

In `php.ini` there are several settings that can be adjusted to create a readable result.

1. `display_errors = On` - this one is not directly related to the question, but for obvious reasons I thought it should be included;
2. `html_errors = On` - php engine will render the errors as a HTML page, not just plain text;
3. `error_prepend_string = "<pre>"` (really important in some cases);
4. `error_append_string = "</pre>"` (really important in some cases).

3 and 4 are needed for when PHP inserts the error in a HTML page with just new line characters and no `<br>` tags. Those settings will encapsulate the error inside a `<pre>` tag, so new line characters will be preserved.

Of course, you can add styles inside the `<pre>` tag. For example, I use

```
"<pre style='white-space: pre-line'>"
```

to allow line breaks on really long lines.